# Add a UIView as a subview to a UITableViewController's view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, subview

I am trying to add a subview to a `UITableViewController`'s view via the following code

```
//In a UITableViewController Implementation file
self.loadingPageView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
self.loadingPageView.frame = self.view.bounds;

self.loadingPageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

[self.view addSubview:loadingPageView];
```

After I run, I get the following display

[image: Image of empty table view on iPad simulator]

Is there a way to hide the table view completely from the display after adding the `UIView` as the subview?

Comment: why are you using a UITableView if you want to hide the tableview?

Comment: What I want to do is to load a subview or overlay on top of the uitableview as a sort of "Loading page" when the user clicks on a refresh button. Can I add a new view on top of the uitableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can add something to the view of a tableViewController. 
I would add both the tableViewController.tableView and the loadingPageView to one superview.